# Finding the limit point of a function's domain

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

For
$$a_n:=\frac{1}{2-x} - \frac{4}{4-x^2}$$
is the limit for $x\to 2$ defined? Wolframalpha says the limit is $-\frac{1}{4}$ but how do I show that?

Alternatively is $2$ a limit point of the domain and how do I show that? I know how to find the limit if $2$ is indeed a cluster point of the domain but I don't quite know how to get there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simplifying your term2 we get $\frac{1}{2-x}-\frac{4}{4-x^2}=-\frac{1}{x+2}$
plugging $x=2$ in the last term we get $-\frac{1}{4}$

Comment: How do I simplify the term to get $-\frac{1}{x+2}$? I'm sorry but it doesn't really seem obvious to me

Comment: @soohyung How would you usually simplify the sum of two fractions?

Comment: By bringing both down to a common denominator?

Comment: @soohyung Well then...

Comment: Ah, I didn't see the obvious solution at first, thanks for the help.